# tvOS , go to Second ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, tvos, apple-tv

I have two View Controller in one StoryBoard.

I want to go to the Second ViewController but when I go to the Second ViewController, I load the first View And Second View together. Therefore when I try to right or left with remote simulator in Second view, I change this function in First view

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didUpdateFocusInContext:(UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext *)context
withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
 { ... }
```

here is my codes :

```
  UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                      bundle:nil];
        UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it.

You need to add this function in the Second ViewController

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator { ... }
```